# Unable to install EE Core - Installation Wizard does not even show up

Tags: install

I downloaded the latest EE core 2.9.0 and pushed the files up to my server. When I go to the admin.php page I just get a blank white page, no installation wizard, nothing. I went through an official EE guide and set the various file permissions that it said to do, still no dice.

Comment: Any clues in your apache server error log?

Comment: Which version of PHP is your server running?